# Application.Caption behaviour: returning Window caption as well

Tags: excel, vba

Application.Caption behaves differently according to whether you’re setting or returning the property.

For example, the following Sub:

```
Sub SetCap()
    With Application
        Debug.Print .Caption ' Returns the default: something like "Microsoft Excel - Book1"
        .Caption = "MyCaption" ' Set the .Caption property to a custom string
        .Windows(1).Caption = "MyWindow" ' Also customise the Window caption
        Debug.Print .Caption ' This still returns "MyCaption - MyWindow"
    End With
End Sub
```

I understand that the application caption and the window caption are two separate things, and by default they will appear in the title of the application together, separated by “ - ”.

You can assign any string you like to Application.Caption.
The curiosity, however, is that when *returning* the Application.Caption, instead of returning the string which you just set, the text will *include* the separator, and the Window caption as well.

Obviously you could split the string by “ - ” and return the first part:

```
Dim Arr As Variant
Arr = split(Application.Caption, “ - ”)
Debug.Print Arr(0)
```

...however this would fail if the actual Caption included such a string. For example if you did:

```
Application.Caption = “First Part – Second Part”
```

... then splitting as above would exclude the second part.

Does anyone know why this behaviour is present? And is there a way to only return the actual Application.Caption, without including the separator and Window caption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can workaround this with …

```
Debug.Print Right$(Application.Caption, Len(Application.Caption) - Len(ActiveWindow.Caption) - 3)
```

to get the caption you originally set before.

Why is it that it returns something else than was set before?
*Because Microsoft made it that way.*

---

Different versions seem to have a different order so

```
If Left$(Application.Caption, Len(ActiveWindow.Caption)) = ActiveWindow.Caption Then
    Debug.Print Right$(Application.Caption, Len(Application.Caption) - Len(ActiveWindow.Caption) - 3)
Else
    Debug.Print Left$(Application.Caption, Len(Application.Caption) - Len(ActiveWindow.Caption) - 3)
End If
```

might always return the correct result.

Comment: @ChrisMelville well my Excel version says "MyBook - MyApplication". So you might need to implement different options for different Excel versions (I use a German Excel 2016 on Windows 10). If it is the other way round in your Excel of course `Left$` then.

Comment: alternatively test if left of `Application.Caption` is same as `ActiveWindow.Caption` and then use `Right$` and else use `Left$` (see my edit above).

Comment: Yes, in English Excel it's Application - Window. Interesting that they're different. Okay thanks. So the basic answer is "Microsoft made it that way" :)

Comment: @ChrisMelville Yes, basically. I cannot imagine any technically reason why it has to be that way, so it must be a Microsoft decision (or a bug). Does this solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the update for 2023.

==================== the Microsoft documentation ====================

I have used the suggestions in the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caption)

*Application.Caption = "Blue Sky Airlines Reservation System"*

and

*If you don't set a name, or if you set the name to Empty, this property returns "Microsoft Excel."*

Use the following subroutine and comment in the lines which set `Application.ActiveWindow.Caption` and `Application.Caption` in turn to test the results are as documented here.

==================== the Windows version ====================

```
Option Explicit

Sub sbCaption()
' with nothing set
' 1. displays "xlwn_Caption.xlsm" in the top bar
' 2. `msgbox Application.ActiveWindow.Caption` returns "xlwn_Caption.xlsm"
' 3. `msgbox Application.Caption` returns "xlwn_Caption.xlsm - Microsoft Excel"
    Application.Caption = "Blue Sky Airlines Reservation System (Application.Caption)"
' 1. displays "xlwn_Caption.xlsm - Blue Sky Airlines Reservation System (Application.Capt" in the top bar
' 2. msgbox Application.ActiveWindow.Caption returns "xlwn_Caption.xlsm"
' 3. msgbox Application.Caption returns "xlwn_Caption.xlsm - Blue Sky Airlines Reservation System (Application.Caption)"
    Application.ActiveWindow.Caption = "BSARS (Application.ActiveWindow.Caption)"
' 1. displays "BSARS (Application.ActiveWindow.Caption) - Blue Sky Airlines Reservation System (Application.Capt..." in the top bar
' 2. msgbox Application.ActiveWindow.Caption returns "BSARS (Application.ActiveWindow.Caption)"
' 3. msgbox Application.Caption returns "BSARS (Application.ActiveWindow.Caption) - Blue Sky Airlines Reservation System (Application.Caption)"
    Application.Caption = ""
' 1. displays "BSARS (Application.ActiveWindow.Caption)" in the top bar
' 2. msgbox Application.ActiveWindow.Caption returns "BSARS (Application.ActiveWindow.Caption)"
' 3. msgbox Application.Caption returns "BSARS (Application.ActiveWindow.Caption) - Excel"
    Application.ActiveWindow.Caption = ""
' 1. displays "Excel" in the top bar
' 2. msgbox Application.ActiveWindow.Caption returns blank
' 3. msgbox Application.Caption returns "Excel"
    Application.Caption = "Empty"
' 1. displays "Empty" in the top bar
' 2. msgbox Application.ActiveWindow.Caption returns blank
' 3. msgbox Application.Caption returns "Empty"
' Finally close and reopen the Workbook
' 1. displays "xlwn_Caption.xlsm" in the top bar

    MsgBox Application.ActiveWindow.Caption
    MsgBox Application.Caption

End Sub
```

Excel version information from About Excel - Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2311 Build 16.0.17029.20028) 64-bit - as at 26th December 2023

Use the comments below to repeat the process on a Mac, in my case a MacBook Air

==================== the Mac version ====================

```
' with nothing set 1. Microsoft Excel top left next to the Apple symbol
' with nothing set 2. xl_Caption top centre (the filename is xl_Caption.xlsm)
    Application.Caption = "Blue Sky Airlines Reservation System (Application.Caption)"
' 1. Microsoft Excel top left next to the Apple symbol
' 2. xl_Caption top centre (the filename is xl_Caption.xlsm)
' 3. msgbox Application.Caption returns  "Blue Sky Airlines Reservation System (Application.Caption)"
    Application.ActiveWindow.Caption = "BSARS (Application.ActiveWindow.Caption)"
' 1. Microsoft Excel top left next to the Apple symbol
' 2. "BSARS (Application.Active" top centre
' 3. msgbox Application.ActiveWindow.Caption returns "BSARS (Application.Active"
' 4. msgbox Application.Caption returns "Blue Sky Airlines Reservation System (Application.Caption)"
    Application.Caption = ""
' 1. displays "Microsoft Excel" top left next to the Apple symbol
' 2. "BSARS (Application.Active" top centre
' 3. msgbox Application.ActiveWindow.Caption returns "BSARS (Application.Active"
' 4. msgbox Application.Caption returns "Microsoft Excel"
    Application.ActiveWindow.Caption = ""
' 1. displays "Microsoft Excel" top left next to the Apple symbol
' 2. displays "BSARS (Application.Active" top centre
' 3. msgbox Application.ActiveWindow.Caption returns blank
' 4. msgbox Application.Caption returns blank
    Application.Caption = "Empty"
' 1. displays "Microsoft Excel" top left next to the Apple symbol
' 2. displays "BSARS (Application.Active" top centre
' 3. msgbox Application.ActiveWindow.Caption returns blank
' 4. msgbox Application.Caption returns "Empty"
' Finally close and reopen the Workbook
'    Application.Caption = "Default - xl_Caption.xlsm Saved to this PC"
' 1. displays "Microsoft Excel" top left next to the Apple symbol
' 2. xl_Caption top centre (the filename is xl_Caption.xlsm)
```

Excel version information from About Excel - Microsoft Excel for Mac - Version 16.80 (23121017) - Licence: Microsoft 365 Subscription - as at 26th December 2023